# MailKit: How to download all attachments locally from a MimeMessage

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit, mimekit

I have looked at other examples online, but I am unable to figure out how to download and store ALL the attachments from a MimeMessage object.
I did look into the WriteTo(), but I could not get it to work.
Also wondering whether attachments will be saved according to the original file name, and type inside the email.
Here is what I have so far:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    client.Connect(Constant.GoogleImapHost, Constant.ImapPort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove(Constant.GoogleOAuth);
    client.Authenticate(Constant.GoogleUserName, Constant.GenericPassword);

    if (client.IsConnected == true)
    {
        FolderAccess inboxAccess = client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        IMailFolder inboxFolder = client.GetFolder(Constant.InboxFolder);
        IList<UniqueId> uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All);

        if (inboxFolder != null & inboxFolder.Unread > 0)
        {
            foreach (UniqueId msgId in uids)
            {
                MimeMessage message = inboxFolder.GetMessage(msgId);

                foreach (MimeEntity attachment in message.Attachments)
                {
                    //need to save all the attachments locally
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to do some sanitization to file names.  Check for dupes, remove bad characters...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is all explained in the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SaveAttachments) in the "How do I save attachments?" section.

Here is a fixed version of the code you posted in your question:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    client.Connect (Constant.GoogleImapHost, Constant.ImapPort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove (Constant.GoogleOAuth);
    client.Authenticate (Constant.GoogleUserName, Constant.GenericPassword);

    client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
    IList<UniqueId> uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.All);

    foreach (UniqueId uid in uids) {
        MimeMessage message = client.Inbox.GetMessage (uid);

        foreach (MimeEntity attachment in message.Attachments) {
            var fileName = attachment.ContentDisposition?.FileName ?? attachment.ContentType.Name;

            using (var stream = File.Create (fileName)) {
                if (attachment is MessagePart) {
                    var rfc822 = (MessagePart) attachment;

                    rfc822.Message.WriteTo (stream);
                } else {
                    var part = (MimePart) attachment;

                    part.Content.DecodeTo (stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes:

1. There's no need to check if `client.IsConnected` after authenticating. If it wasn't connected, it would have thrown an exception in the `Authenticate()` method. It would have thrown an exception in the `Connect()` method as well if it didn't succeed. There is no need to check the `IsConnected` state if you literally just called `Connect()` 2 lines up.
2. Why are you checking `inboxFolder.Unread` if you don't even use it anywhere? If you just want to download unread messages, change your search to be `SearchQuery.NotSeen` which will give you only the message UIDs that have not been read.
3. I removed your `IMailFolder inboxFolder = client.GetFolder(Constant.InboxFolder);` logic because you don't need it. If you are going to do the SEARCH using `client.Inbox`, then don't iterate over the results with a different folder object.

Comment: This will not work for TnefPart (winmail.dat) . ref: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/issues/234

Comment: Sure it will. The above code will save the winmail.dat attachment just fine. That bug report has nothing to do with saving the winmail.dat attachment.

Comment: Just pointing out to other readers that want to process email attachments that they should also handle the winmail.dat tnef structure. If you are unaware of this you might discart winmail.dat while important files might reside in it. Thx for the great library btw!

Comment: Just wanted to comment and say thank you, still thank you all this time on. Your libraries and hard work is awesome! I wish i could give you more upvotes and thanks!

Comment: I figured this is the best place to ask for this - if we have an `IMessageSummary` fetched only with `BodyStructure` instead of a `MimeMessage`, will the `Attachments` property contain a `TnefPart` and will you be able to call `ExtractAttachments()` on it? Asking because of cases where we have a huge mail message which we'd not want to download, but rather only get the TNEF part of it and extract it. (along with the rest of the non-TNEF attachments, which your answer fully covers)

Comment: The `IMessageSummary.Body`/`Attachments`/etc properties use a different data structure than MimeMessage does, so it won't contain a `TnefPart` object. Instead, it will contain a `BodyPartBasic` with the `application/vnd.ms-tnef` mime-type. But yes, onmce you find that `BodyPartBasic`, you can fetch *just* that part from the IMAP server using the ImapFolder.GetBodyPart() method.