# How do I handle downloading e-mails and attachments from an IMAP server in C#?

Tags: asp.net, email, imap

I've been googling and googling and I've found several nuget packages that can do what I want, but for some reason they cost anywhere between 200 and 600 dollars to use?

I've used countless nuget packages in my C# projects over time and I've never seen one that requires me to pay anything for them? I mean, SignalR = free, recapha = free and the list goes on, free free free, but for some reason when I wanna do something as simple as handle e-mails from a server there's no solution without paying (a really expensive price) for it?

So is there a way I can handle pulling down e-mails+attachments from an IMAP mail server without having to pay a fortune for it? What should I be looking into?¨

I'm not paying a dime for pulling dime e-mail from an imap server and getting attachments, so any pay options are irrelevant to this question.

Thanks

Comment: That sort of question is off-topic here because people spout opinions. But you can find the answer on SO anyway: Combine a language tag with a domain tag read the top fifty questions. For example, [C# and IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+imap) shows you the names of some libraries and one of them stands out pretty clearly as the right choice.

Comment: I've looked at most questions I could find in relation to it on SO and I do see the one you mean (I think), but there's no answer given in the question.

Comment: Which question do you mean, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43331004/fnord)?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem! It seems this has everything I need and it's free: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone in the same situation as me I found this to be the best answer to my question:

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

There's tons of questions about this but not one clear answer anywhere, instead there's a bunch of links to questionable solutions.